Ground connection for electric guitar
So, I’m building a cigar box guitar, and I know nothing. So I’m learning as I go. I’ve just learned about the ground wire from the pickups being connected to the bridge so that the strings can be grounded through the amp.
Makes sense…
But aren’t most amps in casings made from plastic or wood, so no metal components touch the ground?
My other project at the moment is a crystal radio, and that literally requires you to drive a wire into the ground (or connect it to something that’s driven into the ground, like the plumbing in your house.) So how can the strings be grounded through the amp if the amp is insulated from the ground?
And what if you’re using an amp like this…
https://www.artistguitars.co.nz/buy/valeton-rh100-rushead-max-pocket-guitar-amp/17979?gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw3P-2BhAEEiwA3yPhwDFF5yxTWl5mIMkXopso5qj4LpDfSlZh-agZpSwnurh0mEsMEtsESBoCWu4QAvD_BwE
Or one that connects wirelessly via Bluetooth, so it never even touches the ground?

Welcome. // As a physics guy it looks to me like you are missing a basic electric concept, the circuit, which literally means a closed loop. Which is closely related to the concept of electric current. Which is closely related to the concept of induction. Which you will face once you "pick up" a hum ... // While you certainly can achieve a lot without knowing all these, I suggest to fill these gaps of knowledge, the sooner, the better.

This may be better posted on the sister electronics site.

I’m voting to close this question because it would be more appropriate on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

@MS-SPO... yes and no... I am familar with the concept of a circuit, I'm just a little hazy on how grounding fits into it. Been composing a question to get to the bottom of that.

As a side note, you don't want to use Bluetooth for connecting instrument because of the latency. The wireless guitar dongles use different radio protocols, and amps often have Bluetooth for playing a backing track through the same speaker.


But aren’t most amps in casings made from plastic or wood, so no metal components touch the ground?


how can the strings be grounded through the amp if the amp is insulated from the ground?

“Ground” is an electrical term which is related to the concept of the thing we call a “floor” when we’re inside, but things can be electrically “grounded” even when they aren’t touching the ground.
First of all, your amp has to have a power cable that has at least two prongs on it. One of those prongs will be called “neutral” and there will be a prong connected to “ground”. On amps with two prong cables, “neutral” and “ground” are in the same prong.
Whatever prong is the ground connection will connect to a specific part of the outlet/socket in the wall. That part inside the outlet will be connected to other things that are connected to other things that are eventually connected to a literal metal spike driven into raw earth that has probably been salted with electrolytes to make it more conductive. This is both literal and electrical ground.
Sometimes a water pipe is used instead of a metal spike. All of these things are hidden from you. The point is that an amp is grounded though the power supply, not through direct contact with the floor or ground.
If you’re using a battery powered amp or wireless guitar system, then your guitar strings will not be connected to an earth ground.

Thank you… this is good information. So…, if battery powered amps aren’t grounded, won’t that cause issues? Wouldn’t that mean that if I exclusively use battery powered amps, then the strings don’t have to be grounded?

Having the strings/bridge of an electric guitar connected to earth (ground) has been the cause of demise for several guitarists over the years. But essential nevertheless. +1.

@Tim I think in those cases the cause of demise was an energized ground plane on some device that was not properly grounded.

@MichaelAtkins-Prescott I suggest thinking about your goals. If you want to make a guitar with the least possible amount of effort, then yes the guitar will still work if you leave the strings/bridge ungrounded. If you want to learn and exercise best practices in guitar building, you’ll ground the bridge and thereby the strings. My understanding is that grounded strings lead to a less noisy guitar, but is probably not necessary if you only use battery powered amps. It also doesn’t seem like grounding the strings is very difficult, so why not do it anyway?

It certainly involved one of those devices, but in addition another, that was really well earthed, otherwise death would not have been the result.

@Tim Accidental electrocution never requires a route to ground or earth, it only requires a route to a potential sufficiently far from another potential. You could easily die by completing the circuit between two unearthed devices if their chassis voltages are different enough. This is why earthing all chassis is the safest option. Blaming a device with an earthed chassis for an electrocution with an unearthed chassis doesn't make any sense. A collection of 1000 properly earthed devices will be safe. Introducing 1 unearthed device will not be safe, and 1000 unearthed devices is not safe.

In my opinion, an earth wire came free and moved across to touch the live terminal on one device, say a mic.amp. Nothing would show, until a guitar, in these cases, plugged into a properly earthed appliance, was touched by the player who then completed the circuit live to earth, through their body.

@ToddWilcox of course the goal is learning. I just like to get an all-round understanding by asking hypothetical questions like “are there some circumstances in which I don’t have to ground?” and “what would be the consequences?” It’s already grounded (like you said, it’s not that hard.) Likewise, the Bluetooth amp is just a hypothetical; I have no plans to use one of those. But you can see how they’d be confusing from a grounding perspective, and how the understanding that situation would lead to a deeper understanding of the concept.

@ToddWilcox… ungrounded strings leading to more noise would be my understanding too. I vaguely remember setting up an ungrounded sound system back in university, and there was a constant hum. So, why wouldn’t I have to worry about this with a battery powered amp? Is it because they’re less powerful (less power = less noise to distort)? Is it because of the shielding battery-powered require? Ultimately I just don’t want to learn the hard way that ungrounded battery-powered amps don’t work, or that I should’ve done something different to use a battery- powered amp.

@MichaelAtkins-Prescott https://www.fralinpickups.com/2018/11/12/understanding-guitar-grounding/

@MichaelAtkins-Prescott Your comments don’t really make sense. You can go try battery powered amps out at your local musical instrument store if you don’t believe the thousands of people who have used them successfully (including me). Since battery powered amps work just fine with regular guitars, there’s no need to make any changes to a guitar to use a battery powered amp. Why would there be? It seems like you’re making completely random uninformed guesses about how electricity works instead of just reading a beginner book on electronics.

May I suggest to add some circuit schematics to your answer? If so, I suggest to include the whole picture, not just some guitar internals. This might resolve some fuzzy or more hand-waving arguments in your answer wrt. "ground". (Same would probably hold for some comments made ...)

@MS-SPO Thanks for your suggestion. Seems like it might be overkill to explain that the power cable grounds and earths an amp, not the cabinet being in contact with anything.

We are in the business of electrostatics, which can lead to unwanted audible noise, when you touch your string AND it's not well connected (in a minute you'll see what that means).
Hope this gives you some insight.
1. Amp with a power socket
To explain the situation let me first explain the first sketch. Please forgive its lousiness, but making it nice would take a while. So you see:

obviously a guitar player, standing on soil (even in a house)
reaching out, touching a string (metal conductor)
the string is connected to the BNCs shield (which keeps away most interference from the inner signal wire)
which in the Amp is somehow connected to ground (here in Germany we have a dedicated mandatory wire for that; it's for safety, not for good sound)
we close this loop via the soil, back to the player.


Now, when you move or walk with the guitar, you separate neutral molecules into polarized or even separated (free) charge, denoted by +Q. Now, a current starts flowing (red loop). It NEEDS to find a way back, to neutralize the charge separation again. If this discharge current is guided like shown, it will hardly interfere with the signal wire, which is amplified.
Touch the string, and there's no discharge noise (which can be a kind of sizzling noise sometimes),
2. Battery powered Amp
(BTW, this covers your Bluetooth related question, i.e. the dvice you linked to)
Now let's have a look at the battery powered Amp. Here the discharge loop is less well defined, if at all. At this point parasitic capacitors come into play, e.g.:

between shield and cable / or both internal Amp-inputs
shield-to-ground (soil) / circuit-to-ground
speaker-to-ground etc.


The largest capacitor (by value) wins: it provides the best path for the discharge current. Remember, every isolated pair of conductors act as ... an electric capacitor, like:

metal-to-metal
metal-to-humideSoil
metal-to-humideAir (rain)
etc.

As you can see, ONE unwanted parasitic loop CAN run via the internal Amp, which you will hear. It's almost impossible to predict what happens in your specific place. Many times (not always), you may not hear anything, just because some parasitic capacitor, which is not attached to the internal signal path in the Amp, takes the discharge current.
Perhaps a design feature, perhaps pure luck. Depends on many conditions.

I think some things are getting a little muddled in translation here. Two points: 1) I think you mean "electrodynamics" and not "electrostatics". In electrostatics, there aren't signals or currents (two concepts you mention in the answer). Signals and currents are dynamic, not static. 2) What does BNC stand for in this answer? When I see that, I think "British Naval Connector", which as far as I know are only used for word clock cables in music technology.

From context I'd guess that BNC is intended for "something something coaxial", and coincidentally the actual BNCs and cables that go with them are coaxial. In any case, if I understand the answer correctly it seems to assume that the strings are grounded because the player has a static charge and this is just wrong.

@ToddWilcox, for clarity: Generation of charge is an effect known from electrostatics. The discharge process is dynamic. Both are covered by electrodynamics (and a few more effects). What I presented is a widely used electric simplification. Kindly search for ESD protection and the like ;-) // The purpose was to show the differences between a power supplied and a battery supplied amplifier, as the OP asked.

I don’t have to search for ESD protection because I know all about it and it has nothing to do with why guitar strings are grounded.

As a self-appointed "physics guy" you might be interested in the term "EMI"

@ojs, to the factual information of your comment: I've been working a long time on EMI and related problems both on PCB and on-chip level. With this in mind: what is your point? Are you saying, you start thinking in closed loops circuits, as we should? Would be progress ;-)

If you're thinking in closed loop circuits, how would you explain that an antenna-shaped conductive object (strings and bridge) may cause interference in a coil next to it (the pickup) when it doesn't have any galvanic connection to the coil?

Please provide a drawing, better a schematic, and I'll be happy to help you along. However, this may exceed the purpose of a comment section ...

I'm sorry, you got it the wrong way round. You're not helping anyone. I think I understand what you're trying to tell, and it implies that you don't understand the problem at all. If you really work in electronics, perhaps you could ask your coworkers.

I got your point AND I strongly disagree about the helping aspect. Bye for now.
